# json country code in php

Tags: php, json

This is my php code:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
//require_once 'csv.php';
$t  = "bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
if (!isset($t)) {
    if (!isset($_GET['signature'])) {
        $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        echo "token = " . $accTok;
        exit;
        $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
            'published_status' => 'published'
        ));
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo $order['id'];
            echo $order['email'];
        }
    }
}
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders               = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
        'published_status' => 'published'
    ));
    $myarray              = array();
    $list[]               = array(
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Financial status',
        'Paid at',
        'Fullfillment Status',
        'Fullfilled at',
        'Accepts Marketing',
        'Currency',
        'Subtotal',
        'Shipping',
        'Taxes',
        'Total',
        'Discount code',
        'Discount Amount',
        'Shipping Method',
        'created at',
        'Lineitem quantity',
        'Lineitem name',
        'Lineitem price',
        'compare at price',
        'Lineitem sku',
        'Lineitem requires shipping',
        'Lineitem taxable',
        'Lineitem fulfillment status',
        'Billing Name',
        'Billing Street',
        'Billing Address1',
        'Billing Address2',
        'Billing Company',
        'Billing City',
        'Billing Zip',
        'Billing Province',
        'Billing Country',
        'Billing Phone',
        'Shipping Name',
        'Shipping Street',
        'Shipping Address1',
        'Shipping Address2',
        'Shipping Company',
        'Shipping City',
        'Shipping Zip',
        'Shipping Province',
        'Shipping Country',
        'Shipping Phone',
        'Notes',
        'Note_attributes',
        'VAT',
        'Cancelled at',
        'Payment Method',
        'Payment Reference',
        'Refund',
        'Vendor',
        'Id',
        'Tags'
    );
    $list                 = array_filter($list);
    $empty_note_attribute = "";
    if (empty($order['note_attributes'])) {
        $empty_note_attribute = "";
    } else {
        $empty_note_attribute = $order['note_attributes'];
    }
    $empty_discount_codes = "";
    if (empty($order['discount_codes'])) {
        $empty_discount_codes = "";
    } else {
        $empty_discount_codes = $order['discount_codes'];
    }


    foreach ($orders as $order) {


$str = file_get_contents('slim-2.json');//give the address of json file  
$json_country = json_decode($str, true);
if(is_array($json_country)) {
foreach ($json_country as $key=>$value) {
if(array_search($order['billing_address']['country'], $value)) 
{
$order['billing_address']['country']=$value['alpha-2'];         
}
if(array_search($order['shipping_address']['country'], $value))         
{
$order['shipping_address']['country']=$value['alpha-2'];        
}
}
}

        $orders_lineitem = $order['line_items'];
        $lineitemcount   = 0;
        foreach ($orders_lineitem as $lineitem) {
            /*
            Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfill_status = "";
            if (empty($order['fulfillment_status'])) {
                $fulfill_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfill_status = $order['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            /*
            Lineitem Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfillment_status = '';
            if (empty($order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'])) {
                $fulfillment_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfillment_status = $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            $variants          = "";
            $variants          = $sc->call('GET', "admin/variants/" . $lineitem['variant_id'] . ".json", array(
                'published_status' => 'published'
            ));
            $requires_shipping = "false";
            if ($lineitem['requires_shipping']) {
                $requires_shipping = "true";
            }
            $lineitem_taxable = "false";
            if ($lineitem['taxable']) {
                $lineitem_taxable = "true";
            }
            //** Accepts Marketting **

            $accepts_marketting = "no";
            if ($order['buyer_accepts_marketing']) {
                $accepts_marketting = "yes";
            }
            $shipping = '';
            if (count($order['shipping_lines']) > 0) {
                $shipping = $order['shipping_lines'][0]['price'];
            }
            /* 
            Fulfilled at
            */
            $created_at = '';
            if (count($order['fulfillments']) > 0) {
                $created_at = $order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'];
            }


        /*
        total tax
        */
        $total_tax='';
        if(count($order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines']) > 0) {
        $total_tax= $order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines'][0]['price'];
        }

            /*  
            Refunded Amount 
            */
            $refund_price = '';
            if (count($order['refunds']) > 0) {
                foreach ($order['refunds'] as $refund) {
            if (count($refund['transactions']) > 0) {
                    $refund_price += $refund['transactions'][0]['receipt']['paid_amount'];
                }
}
            }
            if ('pending' == $fulfill_status || 'partial' == $fulfill_status) {
                $created_at = '';
            }

           if ($lineitemcount == 0) {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    $order['financial_status'],
                    (($order['financial_status'] != 'partially_refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'authorized')? $order['created_at'] : null),
                    $fulfill_status,
                    $created_at,
                    $accepts_marketting,
                    $order['currency'],
                    $order['subtotal_price'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $shipping : 0),
                    $order['total_tax'],
                    $order['total_price'],
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    $order['total_discounts'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_lines'][0]['code'] : null),
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $fulfillment_status,
                    $order['billing_address']['name'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address2'],
                    $order['billing_address']['company'],
                    $order['billing_address']['city'],
                    $order['billing_address']['zip'],
                    $order['billing_address']['province'],
                    $order['billing_address']['country'],
                    $order['billing_address']['phone'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['name'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address2'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['company'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['city'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['zip'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['province'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['country'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['phone'] : null),
                    $order['note'],
                    $empty_note_attribute,
                    (($total_tax!= '0') ? $order['total_tax'] : null),
                    $order['cancelled_at'],
                    $order['payment_details']['credit_card_company'],
                    $order['checkout_id'],
                    (($refund_price > 0) ? $refund_price : 0),
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    $order['id'],
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            } else {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    '',
                    '',
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    '',
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            }
            $lineitemcount++;
        }
    }
    $order  = $_GET;
    $list[] = array_to_csv_download($myarray, // this array is going to be the second row
        "numbers.csv");
    $list   = array_filter($list);
    array_to_csv_download($list);
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
}
function array_to_csv_download($list)
{
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
        //print_r($row); die;
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

This is my output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncOkO.jpg

In my .csv file, in billing country and shipping country is not change.It displayed as full name. But i want as 2-character code(ex: IN,USA)

what is the  error in this code?

Comment: Can you show the contents of slim-2.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the json in `$json_country` array but not using it

```
$str = file_get_contents('slim-2.json');//give the address of json file  

//Change encoding to UTF-8
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');

$json_country = json_decode($str, true);

//Here is the problem you are passing `$str` but you should pass `$json_country`
if(is_array($json_country)) {
  foreach ($json_country as $key=>$value) {
     if(array_search( trim($order['billing_address']['country']), $value)) // Added trim 
     {
       $order['billing_address']['country']=$value['alpha-2'];         
     }

     if(array_search( trim($order['shipping_address']['country']), $value)) // Added trim         
     {
      $order['shipping_address']['country']=$value['alpha-2'];        
     }
  }
}
```

**Update**

I have tested it and found out that it was encoding issue, `file_get_contents` was messing with encoding you need to convert it to UTF-8 so that `json_decode()` can parse it.

Check above code its working now.

Comment: put `echo  $value['alpha-2'];` just after `$order['billing_address']['country']=$value['alpha-2']; ` to see what is showing

Comment: try to test the block by entering `exit($value['alpha-2'])` after `$order['billing_address']['country']=$value['alpha-2'];` to make shre that block is running. it should stop there and give you some value, please reply

Comment: try `var_dump($json_country)` give me what output it gives

Comment: it means your `slim-2.json` file path is not correct, are you sure its on same level

Comment: i need the `slim-2.json` file to help you, try www.pastebin.com again and send me link, or you can do a simple hack. go to http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and paste your json file in var $str = 'content of json' and `$json_country = json_decode($str, true);` and `var_dump($json_country)`, see what u got. if its an array you can paste same in your file and test

Comment: this way you can convert csv to json but i will suggest you to google some alternate `$csv = file_get_contents('region_codes.csv');
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
dd(json_encode($array));`

Comment: just open .txt file in ms excel and save it as .csv file. after that above comment code will help you

Comment: its a helper function which call `var_dump()`;

Comment: `print_r($json_country1)` and send the screenshot

Comment: @saquieb: I think the content of states.csv is not in correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that you have error in these lines:

```
if(is_array($str)) {
    foreach ($str as $key=>$value) {
```

try changing to:

```
if (is_array($json_country)) {
    foreach ($json_country as $key => $value) {
```

Comment: Well, I mean error in logic. As @Saqueib wrote, you are assigning decoded json  data to $json_country, but trying to user $str, which contains json data string.

Comment: Could it be that that full country name from $order['billing_address']['country'] doesn't match any of those defined in slim-2.json?

Comment: Why not, instead of searching in array, compare the exact values, is it possible that key for country name will change? strtolower(trim($order['billing_address']['country'])) == strtolower(trim($value['name']))

Comment: Anyway, it seems that you don't have exactly the same country name in json file, therefore billing address country name stays unchanged.